# NullPointerException may related to InheritableThreadLocal

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, thread-local

I want to use InheritableThreadLocal to store some variables. So I wrote some code like this:

```
public class ThreadContext
{
    private static ThreadLocal current = new InheritableThreadLocal();

    public static HashMap getContext()
    {
        if (current.get() == null) {
            createContext();
        }
        return (HashMap) current.get();
    }

    public static void createNewContext(){
        createContext();
    }

    public static IClientContext getClientContext()
    {
        return (IClientContext) ThreadContext.getContext().get("CLIENT_CONTEXT");
    }

    public static void setClientContext(IClientContext ctx) {
        ThreadContext.getContext().put("CLIENT_CONTEXT", ctx);
    }

    private static void createContext()
    {
        current.set(new HashMap());
    }
}
```

But when other code call getClientContext, NullPointerException happens occasionally:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.xxx.util.ThreadContext.getClientContext(ThreadContext.java:19)
```

It looks like getContext returned a null value. But in getContext, it can not return null.
Because if get returns null, it will create a new one.

```
public static HashMap getContext()
{
    if (current.get() == null) {
        createContext();
    }
    return (HashMap) current.get();
}
```

Any one met this problem before? Or any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this fixes your problem but a clearer way to write this is

```
public class ThreadContext {
private static ThreadLocal<Map<String, IClientContext>>  current = new InheritableThreadLocal<Map<String, IClientContext>>() {
    protected Map<String, IClientContext> initialValue() {
         return new LinkedHashMap<String, IClientContext>();
    }
};

public static IClientContext getClientContext(){
    return ThreadContext.getContext().get("CLIENT_CONTEXT");
}
```

This will mean you use the supported way of initialising the thread local value.

Comment: +1 for making the code thread-safe. The OP's code could return two different maps to two threads. But I don't see how he could get a NPE.

Comment: @JBNizet Agreed but if he is doing something he is not saying it should replace it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks for your suggestion. I also want to know why use LinkedHashMap?

Comment: I prefer to use LHM as it preserves insertion order.  I find this make logging and debugging easier. e.g. when an entry is added it is always at the end.  If you add sorted keys, they remain in the same order so its easier to check its correct.

Comment: Thank`s! Your answer fix my issue with simpleDateFormat in ThreadLocal. Before I was have NPE too.